# Replace values for multiple XML files in a folder using perl

Tags: xml, perl, replace

I have multiple XML files in a folder "c:\srini\perl\in\" ... the structure of all these files are the same ... I need to search for two tags in each XML and if that TAG values has "@@@" in it ...it has to be replaced with "&" ... it has to check for two tag values SHORT_DESC and XXX_NAME ...if any of the TAG value has "@@@" in it ..it has to be replaced with "&"..
Below is the XML file ....

```
<TOPHEADER>
<HEADER>
<NAME>ABC LTD</NAME>
<SHORT_DESC>ABC COMPY @@@ LTD</SHORT_DESC> 
<XXX_NAME>ABC COMPANY FOR XXX AND YYY </XXX_NAME> 
</HEADER>
<HEADER>
<NAME>XYZ LTD</NAME>
<SHORT_DESC>XYZ COMPY @@@ LTD</SHORT_DESC> 
<XXX_NAME>XYZ COMPANY FOR @@@</XXX_NAME> 
</HEADER>
<HEADER>
<NAME>DEF LTD</NAME>
<SHORT_DESC>DEF COMPY AND LTD</SHORT_DESC> 
<XXX_NAME>DEF COMPANY FOR @@@</XXX_NAME> 
</HEADER>
</TOPHEADER>
```

I'm using the below code to replace the tag value for a single file .. but wanted to know if there is a better way to handle multiple files ....

```
open (my $input_file, '<', 'c:\srini\perl\in\test1.xml') or die "unable to open $input_file $!\n";
open (my $output_file, '>', 'c:\srini\perl\in\test1_out.xml') or die "unable to open $output_file $!\n";

my $input;
{
local $/;               #Set record separator to undefined.
$input = <$input_file>; #This allows the whole input file to be read at once.
}
$input =~ s/@@@/&/g;

print {$output_file} $input;

close $input_file or die $!;
close $output_file or die $!;
```

Comment: also is there a way we can edit the same file and replace the value .. i don't want new files to be created with _out extension ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You realize that your output will not be valid XML right? The & needs to be escaped in XML. Hopefully it was just an example and not the real value.

That said, I you want to do this "The XML way"™, for example using XML::Twig, that's pretty simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $dir= shift @ARGV or die "usege: $0 <dir>\n";

foreach my $file ( glob( "$dir/*.xml"))
  { XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { SHORT_DESC => \&replace, # only those elements will be checked
                                    XXX_NAME   => \&replace,
                                  },
                    twig_print_outside_roots => 1,           # the rest will be output as-is
                    keep_spaces => 1,
                  )
             ->parsefile_inplace( $file);                    # the original file will be updated
  }

exit;

sub replace
  { my( $t, $elt)= @_;
    $elt->subs_text( qr/@@@/, '&')->print;
  }
```

The output will be well-formed XML (ie `it will look like <SHORT_DESC>ABC COMPY &amp; LTD</SHORT_DESC>`). If you do need the & not to be escaped, the line in the sub should be `$elt->subs_text( qr/@@@/, '&')->set_asis( 1)->print;`, the call to `set_asis` prevents the text of the element to be escaped.

Make sure your original XML is well-formed though, or it will not be processed (you won't lose the data though).

Comment: Thanks for the update & code mirod .. I ran the code with the actual XMl and "&" value is replaced as "&amp;"  ... is there a way I can replace "&" and not "&amp;"

Answer (score 0):

The `opendir`/`readdir`/`closedir` functions let you iterate over the file systemobjects of a directoy:

```
my $dir = ***dir goes here***;
my $d = opendir();
map {
    if (
        -f "$dir/$_"
        && ($_ =~ "\.xml$")
    ) {
        open (my $input_file, '<', ) or die "unable to open $input_file $!\n";

        my $input;
        {
            local $/;               #Set record separator to undefined.
            $input = <$input_file>; #This allows the whole input file to be read at once.
        }
        close $input_file;

        $input =~ s/@@@/&/g;

        open (my $output_file, '>', "$dir/$_") or die "unable to open $output_file $!\n";
        print {$output_file} $input;

        close $output_file or die $!;
    }
} readdir($d);
closedir($d);
```

Comment: Hi ... Thx for the code ... but I'm getting the below error while executing the code .. Not enough arguments for opendir at replace2.pl line 2, near "$dir or"
Final $ should be \$ or $name at replace2.pl line 6, within string
syntax error at replace2.pl line 6, near "=~ "\*.xml$""
syntax error at replace2.pl line 20, near "}"
Execution of replace2.pl aborted due to compilation errors.