# search and replace multiple xml files in a folder using perl

Tags: regex, xml, perl, replace

I am just entering to the perl world, I got a task to replace multiple xml file in a folder using perl, I tried some of the perl one line code but it does not helped me out, I need a perl code which replace multiple text files in a selected folder. I tried this below post from stackoverflow [Replace values for multiple XML files in a folder using perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456263/replace-values-for-multiple-xml-files-in-a-folder-using-perl) but it also not helped me. Kindly be gentle because I am new, I furnish my tried code from above stackflow post showing error, please see and suggest solution.

```
my $dir = ***D:\Perl***;
my $d = opendir();
map {
    if (
        -f "$dir/$_"
        && ($_ =~ "\.xml$")
    ) {
        open (my $input_file, '<', ) or die "unable to open $input_file $!\n";

        my $input;
        {
            local $/;               #Set record separator to undefined.
            $input = <$input_file>; #This allows the whole input file to be read at once.
        }
        close $input_file;

        $input =~ s/Comment//g;

        open (my $output_file, '>', "$dir/$_") or die "unable to open $output_file $!\n";
        print {$output_file} $input;

        close $output_file or die $!;
    }
} readdir($d);
closedir($d);
```

error

```
syntax error at hello3.pl line 10, near "=~ "\.xml$""
Global symbol "$dir" requires explicit package name at hello3.pl line 23.
Global symbol "$output_file" requires explicit package name at hello3.pl line 23.
syntax error at hello3.pl line 28, near "}"
Global symbol "$d" requires explicit package name at hello3.pl line 28.
Global symbol "$d" requires explicit package name at hello3.pl line 29.
Execution of hello3.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

XML files are in the folder D:\Perl\

```
1.xml
2.xml
3.xml
```

codes in each xml files are follow below

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<root>
<!--This is my comment line 1-->
<subtag>
<element>This is 1.xml file</element>
</subtag>
</root>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to replace?

Comment: replace a specific tag from all xml files, say for example I am removing <!--comment text--> from all xml files

Comment: Why am I seeing uses of `map` instead of `foreach` recently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm impressed as a newcomer to Perl, you've latched on to `map`. `map` is designed to turn an array into a hash - and it *can* do this by evaluating a code block.

However that's pretty nasty, because it creates code that's hard to follow. Why not instead use a `for` (or `foreach`) loop? The key warning sign is 'am I assigning the result of map to a hash (or hashref)?' If the answer is no, then chances are this isn't a good way to do it.

Also: I tend to prefer `glob` over `opendir` for this style of iteration operation.

But most importantly of all:

### Don't use regular expressions and line based parsing for XML

Please, please, please use an XML Parser to parse XML. Doing so via regular expressions is just nasty - it makes brittle unreliable code. There's a bunch of things in the XML spec that makes semantically identical XML (and therefore 'valid' from a perspective of an upstream system) not match your regular expressions. Things like unary tags, line wrapping and splitting tags across lines.

As an example:

```
<XML
><some_tag
att1="1"
att2="2"
att3="3"
></some_tag></XML>
```

Or:

```
<XML><some_tag att1="1" att2="2" att3="3"></some_tag></XML>
```

Or:

```
<XML>
  <some_tag
      att1="1"
      att2="2"
      att3="3"></some_tag>
</XML>
```

Or:

```
<XML>
  <some_tag att1="1" att2="2" att3="3"></some_tag>
</XML>
```

Or:

```
<XML>
  <some_tag att1="1" att2="2" att3="3"/>
</XML>
```

All 'say' basically the same thing (technically there's a minor difference between a 'no text' and a 'null text' in the last example), but as I hope you can clearly see - a line and regex based test to encompass all of them would be difficult. Which is why I keep on suggesting - "use a parser" every time this comes up.

With that in mind - you probably don't actually need to remove comments at all - because they're part of the XML spec, and it's far better to handle them as part of the parse process.

I like [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Twig) and `perl` for this. Other modules exist though, and it may be that you get on with others (like [`XML::LibXML`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::LibXML)) instead.

Oh, and there's an error in your XML the line should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Anyway, with that in mind - to answer your question as asked:

### Removing comments from some XML

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

foreach my $file ( glob("$dir/*.xml") ) {
    my $twig =
        XML::Twig->new( comments => 'drop', pretty_print => 'indented_a' );
    $twig->parsefile($file);
    open( my $output, ">", $file . ".new" ) or warn $!;
    print {$output} $twig->sprint;
    close($output);
}
```

This will turn your sample XML into:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <subtag>
    <element>This is 1.xml file</element>
  </subtag>
</root>
```

### Deleting 'non comment' elements

If you were wanting to delete something other than comments - bearing in mind that comments are a special case - and instead wanted to say, get rid of a particular element:

```
XML::Twig->new( pretty_print => 'indented_a',
                twig_handlers => { 'element' => sub { $_ -> delete } } );
```

Note - this will delete *every* element tag - you can apply more selective criteria either via an xpath expression (e.g. `'subtag/element'`) or use a proper subroutine to handle and parse:

```
sub delete_element_with_file {
    my ( $twig, $element ) = @_;
    if ( $element->text =~ m/file/ ) { $element->delete }
}


my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print  => 'indented_a',
    twig_handlers => { 'subtag/element' => \&delete_element_with_file }
);

##etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement, I am just a beginner not a perfect coder, I got referenced the code from internet and tried. Please I don`t have know the knowledge as you guess any way thanks for your comment.